# Hard disk not detected in usb 3.0 port

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, usb-3

I have a desktop with motherboard 970A-DS3P and using WD My Passport Ultra 1 TB external hard drive. As it was running out of space, I got WD 2TB version hard disk and wanted to take the back up of 1 TB in this. The motherboard has two usb 3.0 port, but the earlier hard disk (1TB) is not detected in usb 3.0 port where as it works in usb 2.0 port. I tried swapping the cables still it didn't work. The new hard disk works well in usb 3.0 port.

1. Why is the 1 TB hard disk not detected in usb 3.0 port?
2. Now when I am taking the backup 1TB hard drive connected to usb 2.0 and 2TB hard disk connected to usb 3.0 port the data is transferring at 30 MB/s speed. why its so slow?

**Copying from 1TB to 2 TB**

[image: fff]

**Copying to local hard drive seems faster**
[image]

**When I connect the 1TB hard disk  to usb 3.0 port I get below messages sometimes**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Theoretically you should be able to get a maximum of 60GB/sec (480Mb/sec for USB2). But maybe there is some contention on the USB bus. Check what the speed would be transferring from USB2 to an internal Sata disk.

Comment: @whs Thanks for reply. I have added images to question, see if that helps to identify the problem.

Comment: Can you clarify how H, F and E are attached - USB2, USB3 or Sata. From the numbers I would guess that H and F are on USB and E is on Sata. Please confirm.

Comment: After I driver upgrade "VIA USB 3.0 Driver" the issue was sorted. http://www.gigabyte.in/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4591#driver

Comment: Thanks for reporting back. That is a classic - bad driver.

Comment: @Santosh: You should add that as an answer below, which you can self-accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I upgraded to latest driver for motherboard 970A-DS3P from gigabyte site the issue was sorted.

http://www.gigabyte.in/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4591#driver

**USB 3.0** VIA USB 3.0 Driver  **Version:** V4.90A    **Release Date:**    2015/03/18

Also, a new version of "Easy Tune6 (AMD)" utility is available.